# How to add nodes and relationship into named graph with neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, data-science, path-finding

Guys I have created my graph using `gds.graph.project` command and this command will make my graph in-memory and it's create a named graph for me.
is there any way to add some nodes or relationship into named (in-memory) graph?
thanks for helping!

Comment: I have huge graph so i can not drop my graph and make it in-memory again